# Codeigniter session getting destroyed after redirect

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, codeigniter-3

May be a duplicate, but the answers on such questions does not work.

1. CodeIgniter version: 3.1.13, the latest.
2. Server Software: Ubuntu 20, Apache, PHP 8.0, PHP 8.1

### What's happening?

Session (logged in user information and other) getting destroyed after being redirected from an external website (probably Payment Gateway page) to the website with POST data.

### Is session getting destroyed after being redirected to the website without POST data?

No.

### Are cookies getting destroyed?

No.

---

*Session Data before getting redirected: [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)*

[image]

*Session Data after getting redirected from **subdomain with POST data** another.example.com.*

[image]

*Session Data after getting redirected from a **different domain without any POST data** example-two.com*

[image]

*Session Data after getting redirected from a **different domain with POST data** example-two.com*

[image]

Comment: Same problem. Codeigniter 3.1.13. Maybe need to post on their git?

Comment: I saw some people reported this issue. However, seems the moderator closing it stating the problem is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

go to system/libraries/Session/session.php
and find below code:

```
ini_set('session.name', $params['cookie_name']);
```

and replace it with this code:

```
ini_set('session.id', $params['cookie_name']);
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the suggestion. Have changed this, but unfortunately it doesn't work.